# Remove Cookies in Worklight Adapter : multiple sessions using same adapter based authentication

Tags: cookies, adapter, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using Worklight Adapters and using Authentication based adapter, which verify credential via a third party webservice (grails server).

When testing with one user, every thing is fine, but once I start using multiple users accounts, I found that all users connect to the same session, with the same Cookie JSESSIONID

I think worklight adapter is adding cookies from previous requests, and that's equivalent to a browser connecting to différent accounts, without removing old cookies / logging out.

When debugging, I can see that I have in the authentication request response headers, when the first user login:

```
"Set-Cookie":"JSESSIONID=63850CB333E7C279DC6D5B1D973B21E7; Path=/"
```

and when the second user login, there is no longer "Set-Cookie" header in the response.

Anyone have a solution, or workarounds ?

How can I force worklight to remove existing cookies when connecting to the authentication webserver ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your adapter procedure you should add the attribute `connectAs="endUser"`. This way each user will create a unique connection to the authentication backend and they will not share the same session ID.

Answer (score 1):

I force a logout on window close.  Something like this:

```
function wlCommonInit() {

    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        WL.Logger.debug("logging out");
        WL.Client.logout();
    };
}
```